# Regex match a string followed by 1 forward slash

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I need to match a string with alphanumeric, underscores and dashes only followed by one or zero forward slash only.

These are valid:

```
aBc
ab-9/
a_C-c/
3-b-c
```

These are invalid:

```
aBc/xyz
1bc/x7z/
hello//
a-b_/89u/13P
```

I am trying this:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,})(?=\\?)
```

But it is not working. It is still matching, for example, this: `a-b_/89u/`

Please help

Comment: Looks like you're looking for `^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+(?=\/?$)`?

Comment: Note that you could also use `^[\w-]+(?=\/?$)`, but depending on your regex engine and/or options, `\w` might also match other Unicode alphanumeric characters (not just English/ASCII ones).

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine I rephrased the questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73676037/regex-to-match-urls-with-2-subdirectories-deep-only , please help me

Comment: Why use a lookahead and inside backslash if you're looking for slash? How about [`^[\w-]+/?$`](https://regex101.com/r/C9nEds/1) and how is your rephrased question's regex related to this? What tool/lang are you using and what's the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a pattern like `(?=\\?)` the positive lookahead will always be true as the question mark makes it optional, so it will match one of more occurrences of `[a-zA-Z0-9-_]`

In this case you could use a capture group for the part that you want, and optionally match `/` at the end of the string.

---

If you don't want to match double hyphens and an optional `/` at the end:

```
^(\w+(?:-\w+)*)\/?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZAThHN/1)

With a lookahead:

```
^\w+(?:-\w+)*(?=\/?$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i8yRe7/1)

Or If you want to allow mixing chars, you can write it as:

```
^[\w+-]+(?=\/?$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f89V9R/1)